# Azure powershell : Find the creator of a user, principal, application and group in Azure AD

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-active-directory

I want to find the **creator of** a given group, user, principal and application in azure active directory (ad), this is using a powershell command or an api that can return this type of information.

Any help please 
Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the [Azure AD Audit Logs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/reports-monitoring/concept-audit-logs) to find this kind of information.  To my knowledge, there are not any PowerShell Cmdlets that allow you to query for this.  Instead, you have to use the [Microsoft Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/directoryaudit), which technically you could call from PowerShell if you wanted to.

Alternatively, you could [export the audit log to blob storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/reports-monitoring/quickstart-azure-monitor-route-logs-to-storage-account) (JSON format), and then use PowerShell to query the logs from there.