# When Was An Azure AD Group Created?

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

I am going through the groups in my Active Directory and I have found some that I don't recognise and were probably created for some development purpose.

How do I find out when they were created and who created them?

**EDIT:**
An [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70736484/) points out the Creation date is on the summary.
This summary also has an Object Id.
Can the Graph API get more info about the group (i.e. who created it) using this Object Id?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creation date is shown in the groups detailed information which is what is seen on selecting the specific groups.

[image]

To get the details who created it, there does not seem to be any easy or obvious ways but you may navigate to the Group which is to be reviewed - Activity - Audit Logs. There this information is captured under "Initiated By" Column.

[image]

Reference: [Azure powershell : Find the creator of a user, principal, application and group in Azure AD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55496562/azure-powershell-find-the-creator-of-a-user-principal-application-and-group)

Comment: That is useful. I just need to know who created it now.

Comment: Edited the answer and added the create related details.